# React test with Jest - onChange never called for Checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, onchange

Why is expect() for onChange on a checkbox not working?

I'm trying to write a test to make sure that the onChange function gets called when a user changes the state of a checkbox. I'm new to working with Jest with React and i don't see what could be wrong. Any help and working example would be nice. Tnx.

Checkbox.js:

```
import React from 'react';

function Checkbox(props) {

    const { checked, onChange } = props;

    return (
        <input onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} checked={checked} type="checkbox" />
    )
}

export default Checkbox;
```

Checkbox.test.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import Checkbox from "./index";

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
    // setup a DOM element as a render target
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
});

it("Checkbox onChange fires", () => {

    // Mock props
    const props = {
        onChange: jest.fn(),
        checked: true
    };

    // Render the component
    act(() => { render(<Checkbox {...props} />, container); });

    // Find the component
    const component = container.querySelector('input');

    // onChange Checkbox
    act(() => { component.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true })); });
    expect(props.onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Test result:

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fix.
Problem was the component 'onChange' was causing React to re-render the component.

Changing this line:

```
act(() => { component.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true })); }
```

into:

```
await act( async() => { Simulate.change(component) });
```

and ofcourse making the test a async function:

```
it("Checkbox renders corretly", async () => {...}
```

fixed the issue.